# При уcтановке пакета libpq ошибка error TRK0005: не удалось обнаружить "CL.exe"

Tags: node.js, npm

в консоле следующее

```
 c:\project\chattest\NodejsWebApp1>npm install libpq

    > libpq@1.8.7 install c:\project\chattest\NodejsWebApp1\node_modules\libpq
    > node-gyp rebuild


c:\project\chattest\NodejsWebApp1\node_modules\libpq>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Сборка проектов в этом решении по одному. Чтобы включить параллельную сборку, добавьте параметр "/m".
TRACKER : error TRK0005: не удалось обнаружить "CL.exe". Не удается найти указанный файл. [c:\project\chattest\NodejsWe
bApp1\node_modules\libpq\build\addon.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\project\chattest\NodejsWebApp1\node_modules\libpq
gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: а в чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: Как решить данную проблему

Comment: похоже оно хочет компилятор с++ от студии. Поэтому, самый простой способ - установить visual studio:)

Answer (score -1):

Проблема была решена переустановкой системы.